# OpenGL Shader binaries not linking in C++

Tags: c++, opengl, binaries

I am currently working on a OpenGL Shader class, that uses SPIR-V to compile the shaders. Getting the compiled binaries from SPIR-V works fine, the problem is, that my program crashes with the OpenGL exception `GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated. <program> has not been linked, or is not a program object.` when trying to bind the Shader with `glUseProgram(m_RendererID)`.

This is my shader creation function:

```
void OpenGLShader::LoadAndCreateShaders(const std::unordered_map<GLenum, std::vector<uint32>> &shaderData)
{
    if (m_RendererID)
        glDeleteProgram(m_RendererID);

    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    m_RendererID = program;

    std::vector<GLuint> shaderRendererIds;
    shaderRendererIds.reserve(shaderData.size());

    for (auto &[stage, data] : shaderData)
    {
        GLuint shaderId = glCreateShader(stage);
        glShaderBinary(1, &shaderId, GL_SHADER_BINARY_FORMAT_SPIR_V, data.data(), (uint32)data.size());
        glSpecializeShader(shaderId, "main", 0, nullptr, nullptr);
        glAttachShader(program, shaderId);

        GLint status;
        glGetShaderiv(shaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
        if (status == GL_FALSE)
        {
            std::cout << "Shader compilation failed" << std::endl;
        }

        shaderRendererIds.emplace_back(shaderId);
    }

    // Link shader program
    glLinkProgram(program);

    int32 isLinked = 0;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, (int32*)&isLinked);
    if (isLinked == GL_FALSE)
    {
        int32 maxLength = 0;
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

        if (maxLength > 0)
        {
            std::vector<GLchar> infoLog(maxLength);
            glGetProgramInfoLog(program, maxLength, &maxLength, &infoLog[0]);
            std::cout << "Shader linking failed: " << &infoLog[0] << std::endl;

            glDeleteProgram(program);
            for (auto id : shaderRendererIds)
                glDeleteShader(id);
        }
    }

    for (auto id : shaderRendererIds)
        glDetachShader(program, id);
}
```

This function basically takes in the compiled sources from SPIR-V and tries to create the OpenGL shader. When I debugged the program, I found out that after `glLinkProgram()` `isLinked` stays `0`, but the `maxLength` variable stays also `0`. So the linking process failed, but didn't give an error. Did anyone have the same issue before?

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct size to pass ```data.size() * sizeof(uint32)```? Why are you multiplying it to size of integer?

Comment: Because `data.size()` returns the element count of the std::vector and by multiplying it with `sizeof(uint32)` I get the size in bytes, that is that the function needs

Comment: Sorry, I looked up the documentation of `glShaderBinary` and I saw that it actually needs the element count and not the size in bytes, but the same issue still remains

Comment: So, ```data``` is array of integers? I am not familiar with precompiled shaders. Why not bytes? Other question, does it happen the same if you compile shaders textually?

Comment: @Can: What errors do you get when you specialize the shader binary?

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't get any errors when I run the function, the program crashes when I try to bind the resulting shader

Comment: @armagedescu the SPIR-V api returns a `CompilationResult` object that contains the binary data as `uint32`. The difference to textually compiled shaders is. that you have to call `glCompileShader` additionally, then OpenGL should also compile the text into binary, so I think missing `glCompileShader` in this context with loading the shader binary directly should be correct right?

Comment: @Can Try to answer this question: data is array of ```integers```? Why not ```bytes```?  There is something fundamental in this question. From documentation:  The binary​ is the loaded SPIR-V itself, with a ```byte``` length of length​. (from here: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/SPIR-V)

Comment: @armagedescu Thanks for the resource, I will rewrite my function and check if it works then, but I used my function in previous projects as well and it worked well there. Is the specification of the binary data new?

Comment: @armagedescu: SPIR-V is [defined as a sequence of words (32-bit LE-encoded unsigned integers)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/SPIR-V/specs/unified1/SPIRV.html#PhysicalLayout).

Comment: @Can: "*I don't get any errors when I run the function*" I don't see you checking for errors after specializing the shader.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes you were right, I added the missing code to my project and to the function above but it did not print anything into the console, so the compilation should be successfull

Comment: @armagedescu I changed the data type to `unsigned char`, but that does not even compile, because the SPIRV_Cross Compiler class needs to get a vector of `uint32`, as written here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Cross#using-the-c-api

Comment: @Can I've seen that. The second question was if your programs behaves similarly when not using precompiled binaries, the classic way.

Comment: @armagedescu I did not test that, I wanted to implement SPIRV right away, that's way the classic way is currently not implemented, btw: I don't know if it helps but this is the hole class: https://github.com/HighLo-Engine/HighLo-Engine/blob/rendering/HighLo/src/Engine/Platform/OpenGL/OpenGLShader.cpp

Comment: @Can: I have a hunch what might be going on here, but before I state what this hunch is, I have two questions: 1. Are you testing this with a Nvidia GPU (and thus the Nvidia OpenGL drivers)? 2. Did you compile to SPIR-V with, or without debugging symbols and reflection data?

Comment: @datenwolf 1. Yes, I am running a Geforce GTX 1060 with 6GB VRAM and 2. yes, I have set in the compile options to generate the debug infos as well with `shaderc::CompileOptions options; options.SetGenerateDebugInfos();`, so that should activate the generation of the debug infos, right?

Comment: @Can: Yes. And this invalidates my hunch (FYI, the Nvidia OpenGL driver isn't conformant with respect to loading SPIR-V binaries that don't have or were stripped of their debugging information. I ran into that problem some time ago, can reproduce it, but yet have to implement a proper MVCE for a bug report).

Comment: @datenwolf ahh good to know, thank you, so I always should generate the debug infos then to be safe, right? What about the release build? Does it work without the debug infos there?